# what are the reasons this unit test is failing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

code:

```
$scope.nextStep = function(route) {
    session.save($scope.sessionViewModel);

    var input = {
        emailAddress : session.account.email,
        caller : 'USERNAME_EXIST'
    };

    webServiceDal.doesWebLoginExist(input).success(function(response) {
        console.log(response.WebLoginAppResponse.errorFlag);
        if ((response.WebLoginAppResponse.errorFlag) && ((response.WebLoginAppResponse.returnCode == 1006) || (response.WebLoginAppResponse.returnCode == 'MSG0307'))) {
        $scope.globalError = $scope.validationViewModel.email.existErrorMessage;
        }
        else
        $location.path(route);
    });
    };
```

test:

```
describe('forgotPasswordCtrl', function() {

    beforeEach(module('forgotPasswordApp'));


    var scope, controller, q, $location, route, deferred, mockSessionService, validationProviderMock, webServDalMock;

    beforeEach(function(){

        var config = {
                urlPath : {
                    match : ""
                }
        };

        validationProviderMock = {

        };

        var response = {

        };

    mockSessionService = {
        account : {
            email : ""
        },
        clear : function(){
            return true;
            }
    };

    webServDalMock = {
        forgotPassword : function(){
            deferred = q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(response);
            return deferred.promise;
        },
        doesWebLoginExist : function(){
            deferred = q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(response);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };

    spyOn(webServDalMock, 'forgotPassword').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(webServDalMock, 'doesWebLoginExist').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(mockSessionService, 'clear').and.callThrough();
}); 

        beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, _$location_, $q){
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $location = _$location_;
        q = $q;
        controller = $controller('forgotPasswordCtrl', { $scope: scope, webServiceDal : webServDalMock, session : mockSessionService, validationProvider : validationProviderMock });
        scope.$apply();
        }));


        it('should call clear method of session', function(){
            scope.cancel();
            expect(mockSessionService.clear).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });

        it('should return the correct url', function(){
            scope.cancel();
            config.urlPath.match("tfgm_customer");
            expect(window.location.assign).toEqual("/web/tfgm_customer");
        });

        it('asf', function(){
            scope.cancel();
            config.urlPath.match("tfgm_customerERROR");
            expect(window.location.assign).toEqual("/web/tfgm_admin");
        });

        it('should call webServiceDal', function(input){
            scope.finish();
            scope.$apply();
            expect(webServDalMock.forgotPassword).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });

        it('should call webServiceDal', function(){
            scope.nextStep(route);
            scope.$apply();
            expect(webServDalMock.doesWebLoginExist).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
 });
```

before each:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, _$location_, $q){
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $location = _$location_;
        q = $q;
        controller = $controller('forgotPasswordCtrl', { $scope: scope, webServiceDal : webServDalMock, session : mockSessionService, validationProvider : validationProviderMock });
        scope.$apply();
        }));
```

cant work out for the life of me why this is not passing? i have called the correct function and the called the expect correctly. i have other files which i have run identical tests on, the only difference is the naming of variables etc. and they pass.
am i missing something simple?

Comment: What is the reason the test is failing?

Comment: Please specify the reason for the failing test.

Comment: Is the test failing because of the expectation not being met, or do you get another message? BTW you don't need to call $apply as you can expect the mock to be called before a digest is run. You'd need $apply to verify the success handler is called.

Comment: @DavinTryon and Wawy - the error message is : undefined is not a function pointing at the scope.nextStep line

Comment: I would need to see how you've defined the beforeEach steps.

Comment: @Wawy added to original quesiton

Comment: How have you defined your mocks?

Comment: If webServDalMock.doesWebLoginExist is only a spy, it will try to call success on the spy which does not exist. you need to stub the method to at least return something you can call success on.

Comment: @Wawy whole test class now posted

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that a deferred promise does not return a `success` function but rather (`then`, `catch` or `finally`), [$q docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

You would have to modify your mock doesWebLoginExist to return a success function when called.

EDIT: 
Something like

```
    doesWebLoginExist : function(){
        return {success: function(cb) {
           cb(response);
        }};
    }
```

Comment: so just where it currently says return deferred.promise you reckon it is return deferred.success?

Comment: how come you have got rid of deferred ? and why does deferred work in all my other cases just not this one? and what does cb stand for? but i will give it a go and see what happens

Comment: cb is your callback function that is defined as a success argument, as I said in my response, a deferred promise does not return a success function, that's why you can't mock it with $q.